# wget recursive limited to children of URL path

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download the following subdomain with the recursive option using `wget`:

```
www.example.com/A/B
```

So if that URL has links to `www.example.com/A/B/C` and `www.example.com/A/B/D`, these two should also be downloaded.

But I don't want anything outside the `www.example.com/A/B` subdomain to be downloaded. For example, if `www.example.com/A/B/C` has a link back to `www.example.com`, the page `www.example.com` should **not** be downloaded.

What `wget` command should I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `--no-parent` option in wget:

> `--no-parent`
>
> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will
>              be downloaded.

Comment: Ah, that's what I'm looking for. The wget options are so numerous that I couldn't find it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-I` option to specify the directory to include in the download:

```
wget -r -I www.example.com/A/B/C,www.example.com/A/B/D
```