# Mirror website with wget but only matching url pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, wget

I want to mirror a website. It's built-on like this.

- abc.com/A/B/1/...
- abc.com/A/D/2/...
- abc.com/A/R/3/...
- abc.com/A/G/4/...
- abc.com/A/F/5/...
- abc.com/A/B/6/...

And I only want to get all links from this link:

- abc.com/A/G/4/...

Is there any command in wget, to get all links only starting like this:  abc.com/A/G/4/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wget recursive limited within subdomain](http://superuser.com/questions/487205/wget-recursive-limited-within-subdomain)

Comment: Yes, there was a good tip for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the solution is `-I`:

```
  -I list
   --include-directories=list
       Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to follow
       when downloading.  Elements of list may contain wildcards.
```

E.g.,

```
wget http://abc.com/A/G/4/ --no-parent -I /A/G/4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of relevant flags:

```
-A acclist --accept acclist
```

(comma-separated glob-style pattern for filenames)

```
-I list
--include-directories=list
```

(comma-separated glob-style pattern for directories)

```
--accept-regex urlregex
```

(takes a regex for full URL)

Generally you would also pass `-r` to recurse, and `-l inf` otherwise the maximum recursion depth is 5. If you want to be able to start and stop the download, `-nc` "no clobber" avoids redownloading existing files. For this, `-E (--adjust-extension)` is also useful, which adds the `.html` extension to HTML pages which lack it; when the extension is present and `-nc` is specified, then `wget` will still read URLs from the on-disk copy of the file.

Here's an example to download a word-by-word translation of the Qur'an:

```
wget -E -nc -l inf -nd -r --no-parent 'http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=1&verse=1' -A '*wordbyword*'
```

It starts at the first verse, and since each page links to the next verses, it eventually downloads all of them. The `-A` option restricts us to just the pages we are interested in.

I think more examples are needed, so please feel free to suggest them and I will try to update this.